# Where are the values in AssemblyInfo.cpp generated from?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

I just started a project on my HP laptop and visual studio has populated the `AssemblyInfo.cpp` file with details from the laptop it would seem:

```
[assembly:AssemblyCompanyAttribute(L"HP")];
[assembly:AssemblyCopyrightAttribute(L"Copyright (c) HP 2017")];
```

Where are those values coming from and can I change them to match the company I work for so that when I create a new project it comes up with the correct values?

Comment: Probably the company is entered while installing VS or in the license key.

Comment: You can reverse-engineer this stuff by looking through the JavaScript code that generates the project.  It is done by the AddAssemblyInfo() function in common.js, out pops the registry key from which it reads this string.  It comes from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion, RegisteredOrganization value.

Comment: I've tried changing that value and rebooting but Visual Studio still makes new projects with the wrong company name.

Answer (score 0):

If it's VC++ project,turn to "Resource View",Double click "Version",you can then set your company name or other informations like file version,Description,etc.

Actually,It should be something like a default name:"" or "".Seems no way for you to "set once,use forever".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but that looks like it's explaining how to programmatically set them rather than how to set visual studio to set the correct company name etc when I'm making a new project in visual studio?

Comment: Im sorry,it's my first answer at stackoverflow,Thanks for your advice.:)